# Should exceptions have their own namespace?

Tags: php, exception, namespaces, composer-php

Let's say I am building an application which has three sub-projects:

1. namespace VendorName\ApplicationName\SubProjectName1;
2. namespace VendorName\ApplicationName\SubProjectName2;
3. namespace VendorName\ApplicationName\SubProjectName3;

Within each of these three namespaces, I might throw an exception.  For instance, `/somePath/ApplicationName/SubProjectName1/SomeClass.php` might include `throw new MyException("Some Message");` which will use the file `/somePath/ApplicationName/SubProjectName1/MyException.php`

If each of these three sub-projects have similar requirements for extended exceptions, should the exceptions use the same namespaces as each of the individual sub-projects as I showed above, or should they use their own namespace such as `VendorName\ApplicationName\Exceptions`?

Note.  I included the composer-php tag as it is related, however, I am not currently using composer for the application in question.

Comment: The question is: do they share common stuff? Then yes, use a common exception from a shared namespace. Should they be distinguishable when catching? Then use specific exceptions that live in the project's namespace

Comment: Here's my 2 cents on this: General exception(such as NotFoundException - which exists by default in php) should not have their own namespace. Custom exceptions should be very rare to begin with since most default php exceptions cover 95% of the cases. But they should have their own namespace. While there's not rule backing up what I said, I've noticed that most packages have their own exceptions when general exceptions don't fit properly(namespace included).

Comment: @NicoHaase  Yes, there is some commonality for some but not all.

Comment: You call them sub-projects which means they can potentially be used independently. If you consider this then the answer is rather obvious: do you really want someone to include the entire application when they only need something from the subproject just because the subproject depends on exceptions in the application?

Comment: @Andrew  Meaning a single namespace for all of them?

Comment: @apokryfos  Good point.  But maybe make the common exceptions a dependency?

Comment: @user1032531  Keep the namespaces separate IF the exception itself is specific to a certain scenario or you want to catch it later on in that specific application and do something with it. If the exception can be used in more than one case(on an entire different application), I wouldn't namespace it at all

Comment: There's no easy answer to that question. It's in my opinion really awkward to include a package called "ProjectExceptions" just to include exception classes, so I'd avoid doing that. However at the same time, shared exceptions usually also share a cause so you can also extract the dependencies that cause those exceptions and put them in their own library.